# extract value of spinner's item and use it in calculation

Tags: java, android, arrays

I developed an app that has 4 spinners, text view , button and each item in spinner each spinner has a value I want users to choose items they want and when they click on a button a calculation be done and shows result in a text view . Where is my mistake? I don't know how to get value.
I'd be glad to find my mistake.

Java Code:

```
  public class MainActivity extends
  AppCompatActivity implements 
  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

Spinner spinner ;
Spinner spinner1 ;
Spinner spinner2 ;
Spinner spinner3 ;
TextView textView;
Button btn;
Time st;
Kind sk;
Hardship sh;
Lang sl;
String text;

 String spin1 = st.getText().toString();
 String spin2 = sk.getText().toString();
 String spin3 = sh.getText().toString();
 String spin4 = sl.getText().toString();

 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(spin1);
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(spin2);
 int num3 = Integer.parseInt(spin3);
 int num4 = Integer.parseInt(spin4);

 int res = 37*num1*num2*num3*num4;


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner3 = findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.result);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btnresult);


    ArrayAdapter<Time> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Time[] {

            new Time( 1, "عادی" ),
            new Time( 1.5, "نیمه فوری" ),
            new Time( 2, "فوری" )
    });

    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


    ArrayAdapter<Kind> spinner1ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Kind[] {

            new Kind( 1, "مهندسی" ),
            new Kind( 2, "علوم اسلامی" ),
            new Kind( 1.5, "فلسفه" ),
            new Kind( 1.5, "حقوق و اسناد تجاری" ),
            new Kind( 1.25, "پزشکی" ),
            new Kind( 1, "سایر رشته ها" )
    });

    spinner1.setAdapter(spinner1ArrayAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<Hardship> spinner2ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Hardship[] {

            new Hardship( 1, "عمومی" ),
            new Hardship( 1.2, "تخصصی" )
    });

    spinner2.setAdapter(spinner2ArrayAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<Lang> spinner3ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Lang[] {

            new Lang( 1.5, "عربی" ),
            new Lang( 1.5, "فرانسه" ),
            new Lang( 1.5, "آلمانی" ),
            new Lang( 1.5, "ترکی استانبولی" ),
            new Lang( 1.5, "ترکی آذری" ),
            new Lang( 1.5, "روسی" ),
            new Lang( 1.5, "ارمنی" ),
            new Lang( 1.75, "اسپانیایی" ),
            new Lang( 1.75, "ایتالیایی" ),
            new Lang( 1.75, "کردی" ),
            new Lang( 2, "چینی" ),
            new Lang( 2, "کره ای" ),
            new Lang( 2, "ژاپنی" ),
            new Lang( 2, "اردو" ),
            new Lang( 2, "مجاری" ),
            new Lang( 2, "سوئدی" ),
            new Lang( 2, "هلندی" ),
            new Lang( 2, "تاجیک" ),
            new Lang( 2, "لهستانی" )
    });

    spinner3.setAdapter(spinner3ArrayAdapter);


}

 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     st = (Time)spinner.getSelectedItem();
     sk = (Kind)spinner1.getSelectedItem();
     sh = (Hardship)spinner2.getSelectedItem();
     sl = (Lang)spinner3.getSelectedItem();


     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             textView.setText(res);
         }
     });


 }

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

 }

 public class Time {

     public double id ;
     public String name ;

     public Time( double _id, String _name )
     {
         id = _id;
         name = _name;
     }

     public String toString()
     {
         return name;
     }
 }

 public class Kind {

     public double id ;
     public String name ;

     public Kind( double _id, String _name )
     {
         id = _id;
         name = _name;
     }

     public String toString()
     {
         return name;
     }
 }

 public class Hardship {

     public double id ;
     public String name ;

     public Hardship( double _id, String _name )
     {
         id = _id;
         name = _name;
     }

     public String toString()
     {
         return name;
     }
 }

 public class Lang {

     public double id ;
     public String name ;

     public Lang( double _id, String _name )
     {
         id = _id;
         name = _name;
     }

     public String toString()
     {
         return name;
     }
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set `onItemSelectedListeners` on spinners. Also there are minor errors in your code. Just try below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner1;
    Spinner spinner2;
    Spinner spinner3;
    TextView textView;
    Button btn;
    Time st;
    Kind sk;
    Hardship sh;
    Lang sl;
    String text;

    String spin1 = "";
    String spin2 = "";
    String spin3 = "";
    String spin4 = "";

    double num1;
    double num2;
    double num3;
    double num4;

    double res = 0.0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner3 = findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.result);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btnresult);


        ArrayAdapter<Time> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Time[]{

                new Time(1, "عادی"),
                new Time(1.5, "نیمه فوری"),
                new Time(2, "فوری")
        });

        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


        ArrayAdapter<Kind> spinner1ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Kind[]{

                new Kind(1, "مهندسی"),
                new Kind(2, "علوم اسلامی"),
                new Kind(1.5, "فلسفه"),
                new Kind(1.5, "حقوق و اسناد تجاری"),
                new Kind(1.25, "پزشکی"),
                new Kind(1, "سایر رشته ها")
        });

        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner1ArrayAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<Hardship> spinner2ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Hardship[]{

                new Hardship(1, "عمومی"),
                new Hardship(1.2, "تخصصی")
        });

        spinner2.setAdapter(spinner2ArrayAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<Lang> spinner3ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Lang[]{

                new Lang(1.5, "عربی"),
                new Lang(1.5, "فرانسه"),
                new Lang(1.5, "آلمانی"),
                new Lang(1.5, "ترکی استانبولی"),
                new Lang(1.5, "ترکی آذری"),
                new Lang(1.5, "روسی"),
                new Lang(1.5, "ارمنی"),
                new Lang(1.75, "اسپانیایی"),
                new Lang(1.75, "ایتالیایی"),
                new Lang(1.75, "کردی"),
                new Lang(2, "چینی"),
                new Lang(2, "کره ای"),
                new Lang(2, "ژاپنی"),
                new Lang(2, "اردو"),
                new Lang(2, "مجاری"),
                new Lang(2, "سوئدی"),
                new Lang(2, "هلندی"),
                new Lang(2, "تاجیک"),
                new Lang(2, "لهستانی")
        });

        spinner3.setAdapter(spinner3ArrayAdapter);


        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                res =37* (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);
                textView.setText(res + "");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.spinner:
                Time time = (Time) spinner.getSelectedItem();
                num1 = time.id;
                spin1 = time.name;

                break;

            case R.id.spinner1:
                Kind kind = (Kind) spinner1.getSelectedItem();
                num2 = kind.id;
                spin2 = kind.name;


                break;
            case R.id.spinner2:
                Hardship hardship = (Hardship) spinner2.getSelectedItem();
                num3 = hardship.id;
                spin3 = hardship.name;
                break;


            case R.id.spinner3:
                Lang lang = (Lang) spinner3.getSelectedItem();
                num4 = lang.id;
                spin4 = lang.name;

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


    public class Time {

        public double id;
        public String name;

        public Time(double _id, String _name) {
            id = _id;
            name = _name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public class Kind {


        public double id;
        public String name;

        public Kind(double _id, String _name) {
            id = _id;
            name = _name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }


    }

    public class Hardship {

        public double id;
        public String name;

        public Hardship(double _id, String _name) {
            id = _id;
            name = _name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public class Lang {

        public double id;
        public String name;

        public Lang(double _id, String _name) {
            id = _id;
            name = _name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . this is the correct answer . the only problem is that it shows only integer I made result double but it still show integer for example : instead of 55.5 it shows 55.0

Comment: i updated my answer, just need to change res variable to double then it will give you result in double.

Comment: if this answer helped you please upvote for it by clicking upper arrow and mark it correct answer by clickikng on tick sign in the left side.

Comment: Thanks a lot it did help me . I marked it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the issue with your code. You just have to add a click listener on your button and get the spinners values. For example :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             st = (Time)spinner.getSelectedItem();
             sk = (Kind)spinner1.getSelectedItem();
             sh = (Hardship)spinner2.getSelectedItem();
             sl = (Lang)spinner3.getSelectedItem();

             // do your calculations
        }
    });
```

Comment: so it's not ncessary to add write these in on\Selected Method?

Comment: if you want to perform an action if a spinner item is selected, you will have to use `onItemSelected` . For your case just add the ClickListener in your `onCreate`. 
You shoud take a look at Butterknife (https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife), it helps remove the boilerplate

Comment: tnx a lot . but why i see error for these codes
 String spin1 = st.getText().toString();
 String spin2 = sk.getText().toString();
 String spin3 = sh.getText().toString();
 String spin4 = sl.getText().toString();

Comment: to get a value from a spinner, you should use `String spin1 = st.getSelectedItem().toString();`